# Hotplugging issue in MicroSD Connector

Tags: sd, hot-plug

I am facing a hotplugging issue in my SD Connector setup. When I plug and check, it reads, however, not when I remove and insert. What might be the reason behind this? Attached are the schematics for your reference. Thanks in advance.
[image: Connector Schematics]

Comment: Maybe your software can't handle the card being disconnected.

Comment: We need a lot more information in order to be able to provide a useful answer. What system is this part of?. What software is being used? Did you write the software for it or did you obtain it from someone else? If so please advise about the software. || It sounds very likely to be a software issue.

Comment: Try resetting the software without powercycling. I'm guessing it will work, which means you need to fix a problem with the SD card driver, or just detect the failure and re-initialize.

Comment: I did not write the software for this, I am part of the hardware and design. I thought it could be a design-related issue, so asked. Well, with the software on board we use UBoot to program.

Comment: Tell the software guys they need to change the UBoot code to respond to the card detect switch. The sd card needs to be initialised and the code is not aware the the card has been removed or inserted.

Comment: @Sam20 rather than adding information a bit/byte at a time it helps to tell us all you know that may be relevant.